# Is there Document Validator available for MongoDB using C# driver?

Tags: mongodb-.net-driver

MongoDB [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document-validation/) talks about how a document validator could be defined on a collection which could be triggered during insert or update.

For example, a collection with email field could be validated using a regex and the insert may succeed or fail depending upon how the collection has been configured at the time of creation.

I have not been able to find similar capability for C# driver for MongoDB.

Is this not supported yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ship may have sailed, but if others stumble across this question. This has been implemented.

The mainline C# driver as well as the legacy C# driver support document validation.  As you see in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document-validation/), you set a validator when you create a collection (or by using `collMod` to add a validator to an existing collection, but I won't discuss this further). The driver includes properties inside the `CreateCollectionOptions` class for the `Validator` document, the `ValidationAction`, and `ValidationLevel`.  `CreateCollectionOptions` is the second argument you pass to the `CreateCollection` function.  Here is [the source code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/3e855051269ecc0db07f61932654ecfe15a14a8f/src/MongoDB.Driver/CreateCollectionOptions.cs) and a test that [creates a collection with a simple validator](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/3e855051269ecc0db07f61932654ecfe15a14a8f/tests/MongoDB.Driver.Tests/MongoDatabaseImplTests.cs#L70-L96) and [another](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/3e855051269ecc0db07f61932654ecfe15a14a8f/tests/MongoDB.Driver.Core.Tests/Core/Operations/CreateCollectionOperationTests.cs#L692-L698).